# What Is the Maximum Number of Reply Urls You Can Have on an Azure AD Application

Tags: azure

The title says it all - is there a maximum number of Reply Url's you can have on an application you define in Azure AD?  I can't find a supportability number for it.

Answer (score 0):

Steve, the [observed] current limit in the Azure AD GUI for Reply URLs is 10.